# Open blog on Tumblr app from other app

Tags: java, android, parsing, uri, tumblr

I want to the Uri for opening a specific blog on Tumblr **app** *not browser* 

For example this Uri to open the user page on Facebook **app** `"fb://profile/" + UserName`

and this is for the Twitter `"twitter://user?screen_name="+ UserName` 


I need the one for Tumblr.



*I wonder also if there is a way to know these Uri of any other apps*

Answer (score 2):

I know it's too late to answer but you can try this `Uri` to open specific blog in Tumblr app

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse("tumblr://x-callback-url/blog?blogName=" + specificBlogName)
```

Hope it will work for you and others who are looking for the same.